# Pattern for continuous rule matching

Tags: sql, design-patterns

I have a continuous stream of messages which are analyzed. The analysis returns different variables, like author, topic, sentiment, word-count and a set of distinct words. Users in the system are able to define rules, which should trigger an alert, when matched. The rules should be stored in a sql-database. A rule is a conjunction of single criteria from the message analysis, i.e. `word-count > 15 && topic = 'StackOverflow' && sentiment > 2.0 && word-set contains 'great'`. Each allowed rule-criteria is provided at the end of the message analysis, after which the rule validation will be triggered and which is implemented in Java.

Every message has to be checked for all the rules defined by all users in the system, which takes up a lot of computation power (there are currently 10+ messages/second and there will be 10.000+ rules to check). Is there a common pattern to speed up the matching process, maybe so that the rules can be checked in parallel, except one-by-one? Is it possible to do this in pure SQL, how would a schema for rules of different types look like?

Comment: SQL is typically for relational databases.  Where is the relational database in this system?

Comment: where are those rules storing,which are defined by user?

Comment: Does each message contain all the fields that you need to resolve any/all of the rules?

Comment: I edited the text and tried to answer your questions there.

Comment: Yes, you could run this in parallel.  Depending on your database, SQL would _sort of_ parallelize this type of behavior automatically.  No, this can't be run in pure SQL - you'd need some form of dynamic SQL at minimum, which means either from an outside application, or a stored procedure.

Comment: Have you looked at event stream querying tools, like [Esper](http://esper.codehaus.org/)? I'm not sure if there is a mechanism for "saving" queries, but perhaps you can serialize them or store the EQL that is used to generate them in your database. It sounds like SQL is just the wrong answer, though.

Comment: @Thomas Owens: We are using Storm for our real-time processing. We could do the rule-matching there, but we need a fast way to filter through the rules to find out which are relevant. To do it in a pure SQL query would be a nice bonus.

Comment: @Thomas I don't see why you need to find which rules are relevant, though. Simply parallelize your rule checking and match each analysis against every single rule. If the rule matches, fire an event that may lead to more complex processing. If the rule doesn't match, it's done. It seems like Storm can help you with the parallelization of data to various stream query language instances, with each instance of something like Esper running a subset of the rules. You would only need to serialize your rules on a system shutdown and reload them on start up.

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with Storm and the only stream query tool I've done anything significant with is Esper, I did find [this blog post about combining Storm and Esper](http://tomdzk.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/storm-esper/). Since Esper statements have representations as Java objects, it looks like you can serialize them like any other object and move them between instances or reload them after a system restart.

Comment: Thanks Thomas Owens, these are great suggestions, which I am going to evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

Your considerations are likely to be more than just the throughput of the matching.  You need to maintain the rules, for instance.

But, let's assume a static set of rules and messages that contain all the fields needed to satisfy all of the rules.  Using SQL, the structure would start with a `message` table.  This table would have an `insert` trigger.  The insert trigger would be responsible for matching to the rules.  What is the best way to do this?

With 10+ messages per second, your processing will be inherently parallel, even when each match is single threaded.  I'm not sure how much effort you need to parallelize the match.  Parallelism in databases generally comes within SQL statements rather than between them.

There are all sorts of solutions.  You could encode the rules as code in a giant stored procedure, for instance.  This would be a nightmare to maintain, might exceed the length limits of stored procedures, and could be painfully slow.

Another crazy idea.  Store the matching messages for a rule in a table, for that rule, and have a constraint only load the ones that match.  Your process then looks like a zillion insert statements.

More seriously, you will go further with code such as:

```
select *
from rules
where . . .
```

The result set would have matching rules.  The `where` clause could be something like:

```
select *
from rules r
where @wordcount > coalesce(r.wordcount, 0) and
      @topic = coalesce(r.topic, @topic) and
      . . .
```

That is, every possible comparison for all the rules would be in the `where` clause.  And, the rules would be pre-processed to identify which clauses they need.

You can even dispense with the external variables, and access the query directly:

```
select *
from rules r cross join inserted i
where i.wordcount > coalesce(r.wordcount, 0) and
      i.topic = coalesce(r.topic, @topic) and
      . . .
```

So, yes, this is feasible in SQL.  And, you can do the matching in parallel.  You just have to do work to get your rules in a format suitable for database comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions, the biggest problem is to actually fit the rules in a common database format, because they can be very different in nature (different operators, numerical values or sets for comparison, etc...)

Comment: @Thomas . . . This is why consultants exist.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved a similar problem in C# though not using SQL.

I stored the rules as serialized XML in the database, for purposes of portability.

At application startup, or when the rule table changed (forcing the rules cache to be flushed) I loaded all the rules from the database and deserialized them into their appropriate classes.

Then as data came in on each app server I executed the rules against the incoming data and for passing rules executed the appropriate action. (At the time I was executing the action in proc on the app server, but now I'd dump it into a queue.)

This has the advantage of spreading out the computation across your app cluster and not keeping it all sucking up cycles on the database machine.